# State and error monad stack with state rollback on error

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I have a problem that I will illustrate through the following example:

Let's say I want to do some computations that can yield a result or an error, while carrying a state. For that, I have the following monad stack:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State ( get, modify, State )
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except ( catchE, throwE, ExceptT )

type MyMonad a = ExceptT String (State [Int]) a
```

So, the state is a list of ints, errors are strings and computations can yield a value of any type "a". I can do things like:

```
putNumber :: Int -> MyMonad ()
putNumber i = lift $ modify (i:)
```

Now, suppose I defined a function that adds the half of the last number to the state:

```
putHalf :: MyMonad ()
putHalf = do
  s <- lift get
  case s of
    (x:_) -> if even x then putNumber (div x 2) else throwE "Number can't be halved"
    [] -> throwE "The state is empty"
```

Using `putHalf` will either add a number to the state and return void, or yield any of the two errors.

If an error occurs, I would like to be able to call an alternative function. I know I can achieve this with catchE by doing something like this:

```
putWithAlternative :: MyMonad ()
putWithAlternative = putHalf `catchE` (\_ -> putNumber 12)
```

In this case, if `putHalf` fails for any reason, the number 12 will be added to the state. Up to this point everything is fine. However, I could define a function that called `putHalf` twice:

```
putHalfTwice :: MyMonad ()
putHalfTwice = putHalf >> putHalf
```

The problem is that if, for example, the state contained only number 2, the first call to `putHalf` would succeed and modify the state, but the second one would fail. I need `putHalfTwice` to do both calls and modify the state twice, or none at all and leave the state as it is. I can't use `catchE` or `putWithAlternative`, because the state is still modified in the first call.

I know the Parsec library does this through its `<|>` and `try` operators. How could I go about defining these myself? Is there any already defined monad transformer that could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, in your problem domain, failure should never modify the state, the most straightforward thing to do is to invert the layers:

```
type MyMonad' a = StateT [Int] (Except String) a
```

Your original monad is isomorphic to:

```
s -> (Either e a, s)
```

so it always returns a new state, whether it succeeds or fails.  This new monad is isomorphic to:

```
s -> Either e (a, s)
```

so it either fails or returns a new state.

The following program recovers from `putHalfTwice` without mangling the state:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

type MyMonad' a = StateT [Int] (Except String) a

putNumber :: Int -> MyMonad' ()
putNumber i = modify (i:)

putHalf :: MyMonad' ()
putHalf = do
  s <- get
  case s of
    (x:_) -> if even x then putNumber (div x 2) else lift $ throwE "Number can't be halved"
    [] -> lift $ throwE "the state is empty"

putHalfTwice :: MyMonad' ()
putHalfTwice = putHalf >> putHalf

foo :: MyMonad' ()
foo = liftCatch catchE putHalfTwice (\_ -> putNumber 12)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ runExcept (runStateT foo [2])
```

Otherwise, if you want backtracking to be optional, then you can write your own `try` that catches, restores the state, and rethrows:

```
try :: MyMonad a -> MyMonad a
try act = do
  s <- lift get
  act `catchE` (\e -> lift (put s) >> throwE e)
```

and then:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

type MyMonad a = ExceptT String (State [Int]) a

putNumber :: Int -> MyMonad ()
putNumber i = lift $ modify (i:)

putHalf :: MyMonad ()
putHalf = do
  s <- lift get
  case s of
    (x:_) -> if even x then putNumber (div x 2) else throwE "Number can't be halved"
    [] -> throwE "The state is empty"

putHalfTwice :: MyMonad ()
putHalfTwice = putHalf >> putHalf

try :: MyMonad a -> MyMonad a
try act = do
  s <- lift get
  act `catchE` (\e -> lift (put s) >> throwE e)

foo :: MyMonad ()
foo = putHalfTwice `catchE` (\_ -> putNumber 12)

bar :: MyMonad ()
bar = try putHalfTwice `catchE` (\_ -> putNumber 12)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ runState (runExceptT foo) [2]
  print $ runState (runExceptT bar) [2]
```

Comment: This works! I wasn't sure if implementing `try` that way would be okay, since I'm keeping copies of the state in memory, but I thinks there is no other way. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have a question though, why do you use `liftCatch` instead of just `lift`?

Comment: `lift` would be enough to lift the type of the expression ``action1 `catchE` action2`` from `Except String` to `MyMonad`, but the arguments `action1` and `action2` wouldn't be lifted -- they'd still have types in the `Except String` monad instead of `MyMonad`.  That's why individual transformers provide a `liftCatch` function, specifically for lifting both the arguments and return value of `liftCatch` through the transformer.